# Send base64string to server but server get corrupted data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, base64

```
//ProfileImageView.image is my uiimageview from where i pick image 

 NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ProfileImageView.image);
 NSString *base64String = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(ProfileImageView.image)
                              base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

 NSString *url=[nsstring stringwithformat@"%@",base64String]
```

I convert that `string (base64String)`  Online and i get proper image but when
     I am sending `ImageBinary (Base64string)` to server, it receives corrupt data

Comment: You may wish to consider providing information on how you send the encoded string to you server.  Also, you might wish to make sure that what your server receives is the same string.

Comment: i send as the server required but still they receive corrupted data:(:(:(

Comment: You are not providing any relevant information to help debug.  I am going to vote this question be closed.

Comment: I think you will not be getting corrupted data but a different one which is degraded quality(due to compression-decompression at Network) . You can check the received base64 string by converting it back to image using some online converter (say http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter). By the way it is not best practice to send image data in base64 string . You should upload image with multipart form-data instead.

Comment: i checked it sir and it work perfectly from my side but when i send it to server,server receive corrupt data. @PANKAJVERMA

Comment: And Corrupt in the sence the size of binary data is increase

Comment: help me plz@gagansharma

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem. For me what was happening was, all the "+" was replaced with "space" after sending to server. There was no other such corruption....It seems ok with android but happened with xcode.

[image]